# How can I reset a pandas multi-index consisting of dates?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a one column multi-index pandas dataframe where the indexes are year and month.

I'm trying to reset it and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jordan Howell/PycharmProjects/algorithmic_trading/ch2_end.py", line 21, in <module>
    print(goog_monthly_return.reset_index(inplace=True))
  File "C:\Users\Jordan Howell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4855, in reset_index
    new_obj.insert(0, name, level_values)
  File "C:\Users\Jordan Howell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3624, in insert
    self._mgr.insert(loc, column, value, allow_duplicates=allow_duplicates)
  File "C:\Users\Jordan Howell\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1177, in insert
    raise ValueError(f"cannot insert {item}, already exists")
ValueError: cannot insert Date, already exists
```

I tried the `reset_index()` command to no avail.  This code should run if you have the packages.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data

start_date = '2001-01-01'
end_date = '2018-01-01'
SRC_DATA_FILENAME = 'goog_data_large.pkl'

try:
    goog_data = pd.read_pickle(SRC_DATA_FILENAME)

except FileNotFoundError:
    print('file not found...downloading the GOOG data')
    goog_data = data.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
    goog_data.to_pickle(SRC_DATA_FILENAME)

goog_monthly_return = goog_data['Adj Close'].pct_change().groupby([goog_data['Adj Close'].index.year,
                                                                   goog_data['Adj Close'].index.month]).mean()

goog_monthly_return = pd.DataFrame(goog_monthly_return)
print(goog_monthly_return.reset_index(inplace=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your code but it seems like there are levels in your index with the same name that you need to remove them first

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).